# jQuery mouseover continuous slideshow loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a continuous loop on hover using setInterval(), but the function which calls the appropriate animation is only being called once.

I'm trying to achieve the effect seen [here](http://www.twelvesaturdays.com/) when you hover products.

Here's what I've got so far in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/476eV/9/).

```
var hoverInterval;

var i = 0;

function doStuff(slides) {
    var count = slides.length;

    slides.eq(i).animate({top:'100px'}, 100);

    if(++i>=count){
        i=0;
    }

    slides.eq(i).animate({top:'0px'}, 100);

    setTimeout(doStuff(), 500);    
}

$(function() {
    $("#slideshow-block").hover(
        function() {
            // call doStuff every 100 milliseconds
            hoverInterval = setInterval(doStuff($(this).children('.slide')), 500);
        },
        function() {
            // stop calling doStuff
            clearInterval(hoverInterval);
        }
    );
});
```

I've seen similar questions posted, but most suggest using CodaSlider and other plugins but because of project specifications I need to do this pure jQuery/js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: also please excuse the horrific looking code, I'm a 95% backend dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `setInterval` you need to wrap your function inside an anonymous function if you want to pass parameters to it. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895006/setinterval-using-a-non-anonymous-function-requiring-parameters-has-to-be-inside).

```
hoverInterval = setInterval(function() {doStuff(parameters)}, 1000);
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johni/TSkwc/1/) based on yours. I made a few additional improvements.

You probably want to reset all data when mouse leaves area:

```
//reset the counter    
i= 0; 
//reset all slides
$(this).children('.slide').animate({top:'100px'}, 0); 
//first one should be in visible area         
$(this).children('.slide').eq(0).animate({top:'0px'}, 0); 
// stop calling doStuff
clearInterval(hoverInterval);
```

And also, having a duplicate ID for "slideshow-block" is [invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute), should be unique for each of them or use [class](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes) instead as I did. This is not directly connected to your problem though, but it is good to know because it can cause [other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983834/what-practical-problem-will-i-face-if-i-use-same-id-more-than-one-time-on-a-pag).

Comment: Thank you very much - accepting this as the answer. Roko's answer also works.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own simplified *plugin* like ***[this one](http://jsbin.com/sepid/3/edit)***:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $.fn.hoverAnimate = function( obj ){
    return this.each(function(){
      var slideTime = obj.slide||300,
          pauseTime = obj.pause||1000,
          el = $(this),
          height = el.outerHeight(true),
          sl = $(">*", el),
          n  = sl.length,
          i  = 0,
          itv;
      function loop(){
        itv = setInterval(function(){
          sl.eq(++i%n).appendTo(el).css({top:height}).animate({top:0},slideTime);
        },pauseTime+slideTime);
      }
      function stop(){
        clearInterval(itv); 
      }
      el.hover(loop, stop); 
    });
  };

  // Use like:
  $("#one").hoverAnimate({slide:600,pause:1000});
  $("#two").hoverAnimate({pause:500});
  $(".someSelectors").hoverAnimate(); // Will use default 300, 1000

});
```